# Is there a top limit about -index

Tags: css, z-index, limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mininum and Maximum value of Z-INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491052/mininum-and-maximum-value-of-z-index)

I see some top z-index in some pages,always 9999,

However is there a top limit about z-index?

Can I set it 9999999?10000000?  Or even more greater?

Thank you

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227738/is-there-an-upper-limit-to-z-index-values-in-web-browsers

Comment: http://softwareas.com/whats-the-maximum-z-index

Comment: Well, some one did an experiment long time ago, just for your reference: http://www.puidokas.com/max-z-index/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227738/is-there-an-upper-limit-to-z-index-values-in-web-browsers):

> Not really, but you might consider the natural limitations of a
>   system, like an int range. I'd probably keep it under 32,767. I've
>   definitely exceeded that in javascript while working on a similar
>   problem, and didn't encounter any problems on the major browsers and
>   platforms that I was concerned about at the time.
>
> In the case of 3rd party ads and overlays, making sure that
>   wmode="transparent" on the flash embed is a common problem along the
>   same lines. Also worth noting that IE has a bug with stacking
>   z-indexes, so if you're not seeing success, make sure you're not
>   hitting your head up against the wall with that one*.
>
> I always like to keep to some kind of convention, and not use
>   arbitrary figures. For example, maybe everything in my css falls
>   between 0 and 10. Maybe dhtml stuff happens in the 100's place values,
>   with a meaningful z-index for any given module.
>
> *Sidenote: The IE bug, to be specific, is that IE considers a new instance of document flow to be a new stacking context for z-index.
>   You need to make sure that your z-indexes aren't being lost in the DOM
>   hierarchy when a child node that would normally be inheriting your
>   z-index is being rendered it's own positioning context.